# Income Tax Return filing for 2022: Home Office and W-2 Employee expense deductions for hybrid employees

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax, home-office

I receive a W-2, as an employee, and I now work a permanent hybrid schedule but I can come into the office if I want to. I'm classified by HR as a hybrid employee. I know the federal home office deduction is suspended for W-2 employees until 2025. But New York State will still accept it on their tax returns. The question is do I have merit to claim the home office deduction?

I work a few days at home and a couple of days in the office. It is not because of covid-19 but the work culture changing as a result of the covid-19 pandemic. On the other hand, my employer allows me to voluntarily come into the office on the days I work remotely. They're not stopping me from coming in. It's optional.

So, with all that being said, can I claim a home office expenses deduction for NY State? I It feels like a gray area. What's my main office? I'm not sure. It's 60-70% remote and 30-40% in the office. My employer is not barring me from the building on the days I work remote and HR classifies me as hybrid. I don't know what the right answer is here.

For the W-2 Employee expenses deduction, can I deduct things you would normally deduct for home office deduction such as a portion of my utility bills, coffee supplies, and my home office square footage?

Edit: The company/HR made a organization-wide decision that majority or even most employees are now classified as hybrid employees. That was not a decision made by the employees. It was decided by the company. The hybrid schedule is, every week, a few days working remotely and 2 days in the office. I have to come into the office 2 days a week. If I want to come into the office on the remote days, I could (I may or may not need to get written permission to do so). But even if I come in, I'd still be classified as a hybrid employee and, as such, they regularly expect me to be working remotely those few days a week. I hope that makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> So, with all that being said, can I claim a home office expenses deduction for NY State?

No. In order for the deduction to be allowed, it must be ordinary and *necessary*. You fail the necessity test since you *can* work from the employer's location, just chose not to.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I can work from the office on remote days. But HR classifies me as a hybrid employee and that was something they decided, not me. It's an organization-wide decision, not just isolated to a few people. The company made the decision that the majority of people work a hybrid of remote and office. That's where I'm getting hung up. Sure, I can choose to come into the office on my designated remote days but the company/HR chose to designate this hybrid schedule company-wide. Ordinary? Company-wide so sounds like yes. Necessary? HR made the choice for people to remote a few days a week.

Comment: @user3621633 I doubt that argument would hold in court. Unreimbursed employee expenses deduction is a red flag for auditors, especially for higher earners.